# Создание фильтра по словам python

Tags: python, текст, фильтрация

Задача такая: отфильтровать предложения, содержащие хоть одно из заданных слов. Мой скрипт парсит сайт, находит названия статей и записывает их в .txt. К примеру: Запрещенные в названии слова - `" а ", " б ", " в "`. Предложения - `"В г д е", "г д ж", "а м и"`. В конечном итоге в текстовик должно записаться только второе предложение, так как оно не содержит запрещенных слов. В данный момент использую `if not " а " in text and not " б " in text and not " в " in text:`, но список запрещенных слов постоянно растет, и использовать такую конструкцию уже неудобно. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = "ваше название"
words = [' а ', ' б ', ' в ']
file = open("file.txt", "w")
is_ok = True
for i in words:
    if i in text:
       is_ok = False
if is_ok:
    file.write(text)
```

Это простой цикл, список можно легко менять, а словари и не нужны.

Comment: спасибо, сам почему-то не додумался